# Get variable name of argument of function TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to set up an quick easy way to test functions in Angular where I would just input the name of functions once in the constructor and test them.
eg:

```
constructor() {
    this.test(this.FucntionName)  <= logs function name and output
  }
```

The issue with this is that if I try to pass a function as an argument without calling it, I get a **this.** scope error. How can I get both the name of the function and its return value when I pass it into the test() function, without having to type two arguments?

Is there a better option, maybe some unit testing frameworks provide this?

My current approach works, but it is clunky and I would like to remove the need for the second argument:

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    ...
  ) {
    this.test(this.FunctionName(), 'FunctionName')// I would like to remove the need to repeat the name as string
  }

  test(sub: any, name) {
    sub.subscribe(
      data => {
        console.group("==========", name, "()    TEST  ===============")
        console.log("Output Type:", typeof data)
        typeof data == 'object' ? console.table(data) : console.log(data);
        console.groupEnd()
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way would be to pass the string, then use bracket notation to look it up on `this`. Use a class field arrow function so the `this` context is correct.

```
test = (methodName) {
    this[methodName]().subscribe(
        data => {
            console.group("==========", methodName, "()    TEST  ===============")
            // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like below (extending the answer of @CertainPerformance)

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    ...
  ) {
    this.test('FunctionName')
  }

  test(name) {
    this[name]().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.group("==========", name, "()    TEST  ===============")
        console.log("Output Type:", typeof data)
        typeof data == 'object' ? console.table(data) : console.log(data);
        console.groupEnd()
      }
    )
  }
```